# Reading from excel using python

Tags: python

I am reading a excel file using xlrd and writing the data to a file. Now the problem I am facing is that in the file I get the integer data from excel as float and where I have someting like 000123 it gets truncated to 123.

I want to read the values from cells and write it in same format in the file.
Is there a way i can read the excel cells as text everywhere ?

Please suggest proper way to do this.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

Please refer the following links. That might help :)

http://scienceoss.com/read-excel-files-from-python/

http://www.python-excel.org/

http://michalisavraam.org/2009/06/manipulating-excel-files-using-python-part-1-reading-files/

Hey, its more proper to search for the query first, then put the question over here.

Comment: if the data in xls is in proper `text` format be it '00123' it is read and written properly to `.txt` file

Comment: still issue not solved....does someone has a sample script that will extract the excel cells as it it present there.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `cell.ctype` if it is `XL_CELL_TEXT` or `XL_CELL_NUMBER` or something else.

(other possible celltypes: `XL_CELL_EMPTY, XL_CELL_DATE, XL_CELL_BOOLEAN, XL_CELL_ERROR, XL_CELL_BLANK`)

If your cell is of type `XL_CELL_TEXT` then you should be able to get the value of '000123'.

If your cell is of type `XL_CELL_NUMBER` then your `cell.value` will probably be '123'. The value of '00123' that can be seen in the excel sheet can be a result of a formatting set in the excel sheet. I suppose this formatting information should be possible to extract from the sheet as well. After you have extracted the formatting information, you should be able to reproduce the value '000123' by combining the formatting information and the original number value of '123'.

However, I am not sure the xlrd module can extract all the the formatting information you need.

Consult the docs: https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html

Or the source source: https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd